# Websockets Server for Unity3d

Tags: unity, server, websocket

Is there any way to implement websocket server, which I can run inside Unity3d standalone linux instance? I gonna connect to it directly from webpage (pure javascript, not Unity3d WebGL). I've tried to look for existing websockets libraries for C#, but the reason they does not fit because Unity3d can execute only Mono libraries with .NET 3.5 (.NET 4.6 in newest Unity3d 2017.1 release).

I have HttpListener server running fine, however for Websockets it needs lots of specific logic. Who knows any solution for this?

Comment: important, for 2020, in practice, you pretty much have to use this library: https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websocket sharp: https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp

It has a unity version which I've used as part of a cross-platform library and on a couple of local multiplayer games, and worked well. I have not tried using the server part of it though - only the client.

That said are you sure you want to have a unity app be the server? It might be more trouble than it's worth to make it discoverable on anything but a local network.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I've used the same library to implement my own Websockets server inside Unity3d. Just required some magic, but it works awesome.

Comment: @Epsiloncool hi when I try running a simple demo on the webGL build I get the error  exception thrown: RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds,RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds in the JavaScript console and it won't even start? Has this happened to you ever? I'm using unity 2018.3.2

Comment: @bluejayke Nah, sorry, I didn't try this with 2018.3.2. My version was 2017.1.

Comment: BTW I just found https://github.com/jirihybek/unity-websocket-webgl and it works perfect with the newest version of unity, even the free version in the webGL player, for you and anyone else out there wondering :)

Comment: With this repo, I'm getting errors with .NET 3.5

Comment: https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client is the way to go now.  unfortunately sharp has problems, and is not really supported now

Answer (score 10):

`System.Net.WebSockets` seems to be completely built-in to .Net and freely available in Unity.

Here's a **full Websockets client for Unity** for example:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using UnityEngine;

public class Comms: MonoBehaviour {
    Uri u = new Uri("ws://blah blah.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3333");
    ClientWebSocket cws = null;
    ArraySegment<byte> buf = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);

    void Start() { Connect(); }

    async void Connect() {
        cws = new ClientWebSocket();
        try {
            await cws.ConnectAsync(u, CancellationToken.None);
            if (cws.State == WebSocketState.Open) Debug.Log("connected");
            SayHello();
            GetStuff();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Debug.Log("woe " + e.Message); }
    }

    async void SayHello() {
        ArraySegment<byte> b = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello"));
        await cws.SendAsync(b, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    async void GetStuff() {
        WebSocketReceiveResult r = await cws.ReceiveAsync(buf, CancellationToken.None);
        Debug.Log("Got: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf.Array, 0, r.Count));
        GetStuff();
    }
}
```

.

One side issue ...

## (Note - For anyone using that sample code, don't forget Unity has no threading.  Using Debug.Log is just a trick for that demo.)

*The three "async" calls in the example happen on some other thread. Just as in Unity whenever you (say) start some calculation thread or use a plugin.  When you get information "back" on those other threads, of course, you absolutely cannot access Unity again. (IE, you can't access any of the actual game objects, their component scripts, or the frame loop in any way in Unity).  What you do is just "leave the information somewhere" for Unity to find. This is a basic of threading in Unity.  (As explained at great length [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54184457/294884) for example.) Please note that in the example code above, I cheaply use "Debug.Log" (which you can use from any thread) as pseudocode.*

## Even more important, don't use my code above!  :O

While my code is not wrong, ***it is not really complete. And there is a huge amount of work to do to really use WS from scratch.***

The only current library is: https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client

We changed a very large project from "my" raw .Net code, to that library. (Alternately I would have had to basically .. rewrite that whole library!)

## And here's what you have to do in Unity! You must use a ConcurrentQueue.

It is completely meaningless to process messages "instantly" in Unity: it is frame based!

Every arriving message: put it in a queue, and process them once each frame:

{Note that *threading* is irrelevant here. It makes no difference, at all, whether your processing that is getting the messages is on the "main" thread, another thread, many threads, or it is being handled by a quantum computer! Each message has to be queued in the frame system.}

```
someLibrary_aMessageHasArrived
    {
        incoming_messages.Enqueue( the message text );
    };
```

and ... this must of course be in a MonoBehavior ...

```
ConcurrentQueue<string> incoming_messages = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
void Update()
{
    if (incoming_messages.TryDequeue(out var message))
    {
        Handle(message); .. your code for handling a message
    }
}
```

So that's what you do with real time messages to a Unity app. (Or any frame-based engine.)

Comment: I remember looking into that a while back but it was not an option since Unity used an ancient version of .NET that didn't include the `WebSockets` library. now with access to 4.6 that's no longer a problem and this is a pretty good option. It is a little bit lower level than the STA-Websockets but that could be a good thing depending on your needs.

Comment: how are you @Mattia .   Right: indeed for client use (I mean, your unity app is a WS client) I can't see any reason you'd use anything else; it couldn't be simpler.  So that's good news.  I'm afraid, I have never tried having a WS server inside a Unity app, so I can't comment on that!   :)  Cheers!

Comment: This is a bit off topic but I thought Unity was single threaded? How do those `async`s work? Is there an exception for `Task`s? Did they make things thread safe and I didn't notice.

Comment: @Mattia , (1) you basically have to use that `async` attribute if, in the function, you're going to `await`.  Don't forget (2) while Unity itself is indeed a single thread, you can of course launch other threads.  This is common for calculations, plugins or whatever.  I am not really a top expert in C#, as such, but I believe when you attribute a function with "async" it indeed means that function will (essentially) run on another thread.  As you point out, threads are utterly meaningless in calls in Unity components, so the call to "Connect", say, does indeed start a new thread,

Comment: , or at least, some sort of new aysnchronous operation courtesy of C#.  Note that indeed, the information you get back you have to "transfer" to the main Unity thread.  **Exactly as explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54184457/294884**  Note that in the cheap example code above, **I'm only using Debug.Log** which you can shoddily run from anywhere, so yeah really in answer to your question the code as presented "wouldn't work" in Unity - you can't change anything in Unity from that other aysnc operation.  (Debug.Log is a cheap shitty exception!)

Comment: @Fattie: "you can't change anything in Unity from that other aysnc operation" -> sure you can, just use smth like this that provides a "run-this-on-main-thread" function: https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher

Comment: hi @LachoTomov - unfortunately that .. doesn't work at all :)  Certainly, you can "access another thread" (the "unity" thread, some other thread, whatever) at any time on any hardware. But it's simply meaningless / of no value in a ***frame-based system***.   This has been explained many, many times, at great length such as my own "famous" explanation here! -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54184457/294884  . If you do read that essay at the link. Consider the "thermometer" example.  Say you did use a library such as the one you mention. The *only thing you can do with it is* ... "set the value!"

Comment: As I say the nature of "threading -like issues" in a frame-based system has been gone over so many times I don't discuss it much any more  :)  But I will check in here, cheers

Comment: @Fattie interesting, I've been using this for a long time with no issues and multithreading works fine with it. But websockets may pose some new issue that I haven't encountered before... I'm in the process of implementing it right now and will see if it works. 
Thanks for the link, will check it a bit later.

Comment: @Fattie yup, it works fine and the async functions can modify unity game objects using that plugin. Your thoughts on frame-based systems may be technically correct, but what you're missing is that there's a very easy way to workaround this. Otherwise how would you make smth like a chat in Unity? You post a message and then your UI gets stuck in the receive loop? Or any time you make a 5 seconds POST request, the UI hangs waiting for it? Unity would have been useless as a game engine. I never really bothered to check how that plugin works, but it does some smart tricks with the Update function.

Comment: @Fattie btw thanks for the websockets code, it's awesome, saved me the need to use libraries.

Comment: BUT WAIT!  Like you, we avoided using libraries.  (The "sharp" one, is in fact, pretty much dead now / doesn't work.)  Pls, read the new part of my answer !  Depending on your needs, you may like us realistically need to use a library.  (If so, this is the only working library ATM https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client  )

Comment: @Fattie ah this is not good... :) I was so happy that I finally got these to work :D My use case is fairy simple and that code seems to work fine for me with a few small additions, like ability to subscribe for events... But indeed it sounds too good to be true, so I'll give it a second thought. Thanks!

Comment: @LachoTomov it would seem to me if it DOES work for you, that's good!  I encountered problems with disconnections and so on .. overall we had top move to a library.  It's a  topuh business; I do not like using libraries myself, but, that's what we had to do in this case.  Hope it helps in some way, sorry I don't have a "definitive" answer!

Answer (score 1):

2021 Answer: Another library which is also built on `System.Net.Websockets` like Fattie's linked Marfusios library, but is made for Unity is the following:

https://github.com/endel/NativeWebSocket

Contains a whole example which is quite simple to get up and running.

Comment: This is currently a link-only answer. You might want to consider posting it as a comment instead, or editing the answer to show a bit more detail about how to use this library.

Comment: @DMGregory Did the policy change since the primary answer was accepted? It is also a link-only.

Comment: I did not happen to see that answer at the time it was posted, only three years later. In my experience, asking someone to flesh out an answer three years later rarely results in changes. But asking someone to improve a freshly posted answer sometimes successfully results in improvements.